# Generate List Of Object From JSON Returning Null Value

Tags: java, json, rest, pojo

Hi **All Stackoverflow Master**,

I am in the middle of development an application that consumed a JSON from some rest webservice.

Sample JSON here on this link http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=VYESA9MG (this is due to JSON that a little bit long)

I create a POJO class that cater for this JSON model as below:

```
public final class BusSyncAdapterModel {
public final Route routes[];

public BusSyncAdapterModel(Route[] routes){
    this.routes = routes;
}

public static final class Route {
    public final Route route[];
    public final Stop stops[];

    public Route(Route[] route, Stop[] stops){
        this.route = route;
        this.stops = stops;
    }

    public static final class Routes {
        public final End end;
        public final Routes route;
        public final Start start;
        public final Stop stops[];
        public final Trip trip;

        public Routes(End end, Routes route, Start start, Stop[] stops, Trip trip){
            this.end = end;
            this.route = route;
            this.start = start;
            this.stops = stops;
            this.trip = trip;
        }

        public static final class End {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final double[] location;
            public final String name;

            public End(String code, long id, double[] location, String name){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.location = location;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }

        public static final class RouteList {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final String name;
            public final long type;

            public RouteList(String code, long id, String name, long type){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.type = type;
            }
        }

        public static final class Start {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final double[] location;
            public final String name;

            public Start(String code, long id, double[] location, String name){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.location = location;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }

        public static final class Stop {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final long is_wp;
            public final String line;
            public final double[] location;
            public final String name;

            public Stop(String code, long id, long is_wp, String line, double[] location, String name){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.is_wp = is_wp;
                this.line = line;
                this.location = location;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }

        public static final class Trip {
            public final String headsign;
            public final long id;

            public Trip(String headsign, long id){
                this.headsign = headsign;
                this.id = id;
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class Stop {
        public final Route route;
        public final Stop stop;
        public final Trip trip;

        public Stop(Route route, Stop stop, Trip trip){
            this.route = route;
            this.stop = stop;
            this.trip = trip;
        }

        public static final class RouteTrip {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final String name;
            public final long type;

            public RouteTrip(String code, long id, String name, long type){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.type = type;
            }
        }

        public static final class StopPoints {
            public final String code;
            public final long id;
            public final double[] location;
            public final String name;

            public StopPoints(String code, long id, double[] location, String name){
                this.code = code;
                this.id = id;
                this.location = location;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }

        public static final class Trip {
            public final String headsign;
            public final long id;

            public Trip(String headsign, long id){
                this.headsign = headsign;
                this.id = id;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This model is called in our code that using GSON module. Currently i already catch JSON and it is understand that the JSON have two list of routes. (please see the JSON sample up there) But the value is null.

This is my code looks like:

```
private List<BusStopPointsModel> getListBusStopObject(String busRouteCode) {
    List<BusStopPointsModel> listOfBusStopObject = new ArrayList<BusStopPointsModel>();

    /* load configuration properties */
    Prasarana prasarana = new ApiLoader().new Prasarana();

    /* do REST web service call */
    WebResource webResource = null;
    try {
        Client client = Client.create();
        webResource = client.resource(prasarana.getEndpointURL());

        MultivaluedMap<String,String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
            queryParams.add("route", busRouteCode);

        ClientResponse response = webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            logger.info(Constants.SyncAdapter.HTTP_NOTOK_400_BUS + response.getStatus());
            throw new RuntimeException(Constants.SyncAdapter.HTTP_NOTOK_400_BUS + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            logger.info(Constants.SyncAdapter.HTTP_OK_200_BUS);

            /* print out the status from server */
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            JsonObject jsonRoutesObject = new JsonParser().parse(output).getAsJsonObject();

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            List<BusSyncAdapterModel> listOfBusSyncAdapterModel = new ArrayList<BusSyncAdapterModel>();

            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<BusSyncAdapterModel>>() {}.getType();
            listOfBusSyncAdapterModel = gson.fromJson(jsonRoutesObject.get("routes"), listType);

            System.out.println(listOfBusSyncAdapterModel);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getCause());
    } 

    return listOfBusStopObject;
}
```

Is there any ideas why this is falling? Perhaps wrong POJO model?

Comment: At a quick glance, the first problem I see is that the model classes don't have default constuctors. I don't use Gson, but I imagine that is a problem, as the it will not know how to create the bean. I know with Jackson, it is a problem.

Comment: @peeskillet i do welcome for any suggestion. What do you mean with Jackson, it is a problem?

Comment: I mean with Jackson (a different JSON framework), if there is no default constructor (and without further configuration) it will not know how to construct the objects.

Comment: @randytan are you sure getting output  as nonnull value?

Comment: @HBdroid yes the output list is known to have two arraylist. But inside the list, it is empty. I try to change it into Jackson now.

Answer (score 0):

Hello [here](https://github.com/tianzhijiexian/JsonAnnotation)  is the library from github you can generate class according to your json data and can get data accordingly

`@Json2Model(modelName = "UserInfo",jsonStr = "Your Json data here";`

```
 String SEARCH_URSER_INFO = "search/user";
```

- Finaly you will get your response through json

  UserInfo userinfo = new Gson().from("yourdatagain",UserInfo.class);

Comment: what do you mean with SEARCH_USER_INFO? what that String is for?

Comment: @randytan its only package Name which will be available in your buil/generated/apt/debug/search/user